# не парсит данные

Tags: python, requests

Надо спарсить данные, название бренда, цену. Сайт динамический. Парсит только первые 32 значения, остальне не берет. Откуда можно подтянуть остальные данные? JSON не нашел, быть может есть какой то другой вариант? Желательно с помощью requests.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time

url = 'https://www.zalando.co.uk/men/?q=hoodie&order=price&dir=asc'
headers = {
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0'
}
r = requests.post(url, headers = headers)
#print(r.status_code)

src = r.text
soup = bs(src, 'lxml')
items = soup.find_all('div', class_='DT5BTM w8MdNG cYylcv _1FGXgy _75qWlu iOzucJ JT3_zV vut4p9')
num = 0
for i in items:
    num = num + 1
    print(num)
    try:
        brand_name = i.find('div', class_='_3KN5mc').find('h3')
        print(brand_name)
        time.sleep(1)
    except Exception:
        data = "None"
        print(data)
```

Comment: Ну видимо `Selenium`, раз сайт динамический

Comment: Если сайт динамический, значит он через ajax подгружает данные по товарам. Надо понять как он это делает и повторить этот запрос уже в своем скрипте.

Comment: В этом и проблема, не понимаю как он подгружает данные, ajax нет

Comment: А нет ни какого запроса. Все данные есть в исходном HTML

Comment: А почему тогда берутся данные для 32 значений? Остальные не прогружаются

Comment: Потому что, надо анализировать сам HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Продукты запрашиваются через POST запрос на https://www.zalando.co.uk/api/graphql/
увидеть это вы можете открыв консоль (F12) перейти на вкладку Network => Fetch/XHR

Comment: Да, это видел, но эта ссылка не рабочая

Comment: @erohin94 VPN в помощь

Comment: Благодарю, попробовал в другом браузере и ссылка заработала. И после того как почистил куки, заработало и в первом браузере.

Answer (score 2):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json

url = 'https://www.zalando.co.uk/men/?q=hoodie&p=1&order=price&dir=asc'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0'
}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')
items = soup.find('script', class_="re-data-el-hydrate")
dct = json.loads(items.text)['graphqlCache']
qq = (z['data']['product']['name'] for x, z in dct.items() if '8a351c55e39' in x)
for i,x in enumerate(qq, 1):
    print(i, x)

1 CORE HOODIE BIG & TALL - Hoodie - dusty pink
2 EMBROIDERED - Sweatshirt - light green

...

83 RAINBOW HEART HOODIE PRIDE UNISEX - Hoodie - black
84 UNISEX - Hoodie - bordeaux
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Теперь возник другой вопрос, почему если открываю среду разработчика в браузере и во вкладке элементы пытаюсь найти класс class_="re-data-el-hydrate", то он не находится. А если страницу html сохраняю в скрипте  with open("index.html", "w", encoding='UTF-8') as file:
    file.write(src). То если ее открыть и вбить в поиск данный класс, то он находится без проблем?

Comment: Скаченный исходник, в браузере паработал JS который кординально может отличатся от исходника